# I can't restart my dnsmasq service, so my fog server won't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, fog, dnsmasq

I have a `fog server` set up in work, every now and then our useless internet fails and I have to reset the `dnsmasq` to get it working again, (don't have a `dhcp` server set up and can't modify the hubs settings so won't be doing this). Whenever I try `sudo dnsmasq restart`, I get the message:

> junk found in command line.

First of all, can some please explain to me in simple terms what this actually means? As I am no Linux expert and nobody seems to have a simple explanation as to what this is...

Secondly, I have always used the command posted on another the `fog` forum to correct this error.

```sh
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

This always worked perfectly however now when I try to run this command I get the message:

> command not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sudo restart dnsmasq. The /etc/init.d/ directory is the location of System V init scripts. If dnsmasq is not there, it's probably been converted to use upstart and its configuration is in /etc/init/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and the explanation, if I try the command you suggested I get the message unknown job: dnsmasq, also I checked the etc/init.d/ directory and dnsmasq is there if that helps

Comment: So dnsmasq is still a System V script. Maybe running the script line by line will show what's wrong: sudo sh -x /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart

Comment: I figured it out, to run the sudo etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart command I had to navigate from my user back to the top of the file system, simple solution but something I just didn't think of, thanks for the step by step command though, very interesting

Comment: add a / before etc and you can use the command from anywhere. Alternatively use 'sudo service dnsmasq restart'. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 14):

Edit your /etc/init.d/dnsmasq

My linux distribution is Debian 9 (stretch)

Change this line :

```
ROOT_DS="/usr/share/dns/root.ds"

if [ -f $ROOT_DS ]; then
   DNSMASQ_OPTS="$DNSMASQ_OPTS `sed -e s/". IN DS "/--trust-anchor=.,/ -e s/" "/,/g $ROOT_DS | tr '\n' ' '`" 
fi
```

To :

```
ROOT_DS="/usr/share/dns/root.ds"

if [ -f $ROOT_DS ]; then
   DNSMASQ_OPTS="$DNSMASQ_OPTS `sed -e s/".*IN[[:space:]]DS[[:space:]]"/--trust-anchor=.,/ -e s/"[[:space:]]"/,/g $ROOT_DS | tr '\n' ' '`" 
fi
```

This problem occurs due to updating the dns-root-data package, more precisely in the file **/usr/share/dns/root.ds**.

The structure of this file was changed, the fields were separated only by spaces, now they were changed by tabs (**\t**)

Comment: Thanks! This really saved me a lot of time this morning on my Debian 9 machine.

Comment: I just saw this answer, but I had the same issue. I purged then reinstalled dnsmasq and that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Using awk seems to be more clear and is independent of whitespace type:

DNSMASQ_OPTS="$DNSMASQ_OPTS `mawk -- '{ printf " --trust-anchor=.,%d,%d,%d,%s", $5, $6, $7, $8 }' $ROOT_DS`"

Comment: Thanks Gaia for the "whitespace free" solution!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo service dnsmasq start`

That worked for me

Comment: Also, `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq` does the same job.